# Extract trajectory from recurrence plot

Tags: numerical-methods, recurrence-relations, signal-processing

Let's say I have a time series in a vector $v$, and I compute its recurrence(-like) plot $R(i,j)=\left \| v(i)-v(j)  \right \|$.

Is there any standard way of extracting $v$ knowing only $R(i,j)$ ??

See wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_plot for examples of what I mean. In the main figure there are four examples of 1D signals converted to recurrence plot.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It isn’t possible to recover v from its recurrence plot. The recurrence plot doesn’t retain enough information about v, because two vectors can have the same recurrence plot.

Comment: Thanks. Surely it's possible within a constant, isn't it? The only way I can see two vectors having the same recurrence plot is if they differ by an additive constant, is that incorrect?

Comment: @user655870 The plot is invariant under the transformation $x \gets ax + b$ where $a$ is a scalar with unit modulus and $b$ is a vector.

Comment: So is there a way to find one possible solution? Even if it's not unique?